# Ionic no splash and icon after SDK update

Tags: android, ionic-framework, icons, splash-screen

I didn't change anything except updating the SDK. After I removed and added the platform, it builds with default ionic icon and splash.

I tried also making a new project, and generating only splash and icon for it, and same thing happens...images get generated, they are in folders they need to be, and paths in config are right.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

EDIT: Everything gets compiled with JDK 1.8.0_101

Comment: r u using Android Studio

Comment: no, Ionic framework

Answer (score 0):

check out this link: 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1608
and specifically florentsuc's comment

i solved it by running:
ionic platform remove android
ionic platform add android@6.1.0